# Inner join in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

this is the error...

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 23000/1052

Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_vendor` INNER JOIN `tbl_item` ON `id`=`vendor_id` WHERE `shop` = 'BVC'

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/parts/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

```
$shop= $this->input->post('vendor');
                      $this->db->select('id');
                      $this->db->from('tbl_vendor');
                      $this->db->join('tbl_item', 'vendor_id=id', 'inner');
                      $this->db->where('shop', $shop);
                      $query=$this->db->get();
```

Comment: use id with table alias i.e. tbl_vendor.id

Comment: i will use it in select() or in join()?

Comment: both place , whenever you have common column name in both table use the alias to differentiate column

Comment: if i do it. i will again get the error. Message: Object of class CI_DB_pdo_result could not be converted to string

Filename: database/DB_driver.php    @s

Comment: what is that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have to columns the same try something like this

```
$shop = $this->input->post('vendor');

$query = $this->db->select('i.id, v.id as vender_id')
                  ->from('tbl_vendor v')
                  ->join('tbl_item i', 'i.id = v.id')
                  ->where('v.shop', $shop)
                  ->get();

return $query->row_array();
```

Note:

- row_array() will return single item
- result_array() multiple items

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: @AliHassan don't for get to vote up and accept answer

Comment: single letter ambiguous need to be avoided.table name as ambiguous is best. @wolfgang1983

Comment: @wolfgang1983 now i can't even insert the data in db. it neither show error nor insert the data in db.

Comment: That is not part of the original question

Comment: @wolfgang1983 but i also want to insert that data as well.. but now i can't.

Comment: You are going to have to ask another question for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the table name as ambiguous like below:

```
$shop= $this->input->post('vendor');
                      $this->db->select('tbl_vendor.id');
                      $this->db->from('tbl_vendor');
                      $this->db->join('tbl_item', 'tbl_item.id=tbl_vendor.id','inner');
                      $this->db->where('tbl_vendor.shop', $shop);
                      $query=$this->db->get();
                      $data=$query->result_array();
```

so that query will be
`SELECT tbl_vendor.id FROM tbl_vendor INNER JOIN tbl_item ON tbl_vendor.id=tbl_item.id WHERE tbl_vendor.shop = 'BVC`'

More information check [here](http://www.bsourcecode.com/codeigniter/codeigniter-join-query/)

Comment: try like this? @Ali Hassan

Comment: if i do this i again get the error.. Message: Object of class CI_DB_pdo_result could not be converted to string

Filename: database/DB_driver.php

Comment: here i dont know what are the column name belongs to which table.you need to use your table name before that column name

Comment: the **ID** in Select() is belog from **tbl_vendor** and in join() i want to make the inner join of **tbl_vendor.id** with **tbl_item.id**.

Answer (score 0):

The error you receive means the field name "id" exists in one or more of the tables you are querying, can you please write which columns you have in each table?
Giving a table an alias and using it together with your field will solve your problem: For example tbl_vendor.id